# How to get html page language in node.js?

Tags: node.js, nlp

How do I get which language html page is written in with nodejs? I don't care about 100% accuracy, just something simple to tell if it's English, Russian, German etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a language detection library in pure javascript:
http://mazko.github.io/jsli/